# Google Earth Engine - Sentinel NO2 mean, min, max chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, sentinel-5p

I'm using the code bottom to create NO2 Charts of a region.
Please, do you know if it possible to group the three graphs into one?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
.select('NO2_column_number_density')
.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-04-30');
  
var mean=ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30).setOptions({title: 'NO2 mean'});
var max=ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geometry, ee.Reducer.max(), 30).setOptions({title: 'NO2 max'});;
var min=ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geometry, ee.Reducer.min(), 30).setOptions({title: 'NO2 min'});;
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/07ae3abea736fc50c09964a616ff986a)

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature()` function. Make a feature collection with a property for each image for mean, min and max value. Then plot the chart.

```
var feats = collection.map(function(image){
  var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine(ee.Reducer.max(), '', true).combine(ee.Reducer.min(),'', true);
  var stats = image.reduceRegion(reducers, geometry, 1000);
  return ee.Feature(null, stats).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// plot that feature collectioin
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(feats, 'system:time_start')
                .setSeriesNames(['NO2 mean', 'NO2 max', 'NO2 min']);
print(chart)
```

Also note that you better filter the collection on the boundaries of the geometry:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-04-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry);
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cd2a9046bc0707257e643aef8ad44e2). Note that I draw an dummy geometry and increased the scale to reduce computation time. A scale of 30m might be unnecasarry high for 0.01 arc degrees scale images.

Comment: Thank you very nuch @Kuik. your answer allowed me to understand many new things that will be useful for other projects